# Trying to export all but two specific sheets to Individual PDF's named with the Tab's name

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a spreadsheet where I would like to have each worksheet exported into their own individual PDF file; however I want to ignore two of the tabs which the data pulls from. I prefer to ignore the two instead of listing the others, because if we add sheets those would need to be exported as well.

I'm also self-taught in vba so if there's any good coding practices that I can improve on I welcome those tips as well.

So far I have the following:

```
Sub SheetsToPDFs()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nm As String
nm = ws.Name

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If nm <> "Tab 1 Name" And nm <> "Tab 2 Name" Then
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=nm & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

I expected this to ignore those two tabs (names are different text, but figured to keep it general), and export everything else as it's own sheet in the current folder (may add a specific path later on). However I am getting the error "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".

Comment: Move this line `nm = ws.Name` after the `For Each..` line

Comment: Awesome, This worked! Can you explain why this fixed it for my own learning?

Comment: Because in each loop the variable nm which is equal to ws.Name will be different each time so you have to put it inside the loop.

Comment: @MarkS. you are looping and want to capture the ws.name DURING the loop.  if you have the ws.name outside of the loop, you only capture one and name everything the same (or in this case ws.name = nothing since you haven't defined ws yet.  For the future, if you need to have a response, or want to respond to someoen, use an "@" tag

Comment: @YasserKhalil Thank you, that makes much more sense. Thank you for your concise, effective and quick answer. Added thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @YasserKhalil for the change that I needed. The `nm = ws.name` needed to moved into the For loop so as it changed the macro would recognize this change.

I also added a Period written in it so that as the files are exported the period is in the file name to eliminate the risk of saving over previous versions (this report is a monthly report).

```
Sub SheetsToPDFs()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nm As String
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Period As String
Period = Month(Date) & "." & Year(Date)

     For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     nm = ws.Name
         If nm <> "Tab Name 1" And nm <> "Tab Name 2" Then
            ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=nm & " " & Period & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
        End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: No need to use named ranges for the variable `Period'. You can use the VBA functions `Period = Month(Date) & "." & Year(Date)`